# aws distributed loadtesting with csv

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a jmeter script that tests login flow for different users. I use csv option to read username and password.
But aws distributed load testing doesn't allow me to do so
.What can I do to load test?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the CSV file to all JMeter Slave machines, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html):

> If the test uses any data files, **note that these are not sent across by the client so make sure that these are available in the appropriate directory on each server.**

If for some reason you cannot do this you will have to consider alternative solutions so all slaves would be able to get the credentials from a centralized storage, available options are in:

- Put your credentials into the database and use JDBC Test Elements for reading them, see [How to Automatically Pull Data from a DB for Your Performance Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-automatically-pull-data-from-a-db-for-your-performance-test) article for more details
- [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) provides simple HTTP interface for reading data from CSV files
- [Redis Data Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) allows reading data from [Redis](https://redis.io/) storage

Comment: is it possible in aws distributed load testing tool?